# dtN.filter for slow typers

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-turbotable

When using `dtN.filter` slow typers get a refresh and then it show the filtered data but there is no possibility to type further as the input element is not focused.

`<input *ngSwitchCase="'MasterData.Name'" pInputText type="text" [(ngModel)]="colFilter_2"
          (input)="dtN.filter($event.target.value, col.field, col.filterMatchMode);">`

1. Is there a global setting of some sort to set the timeout of this so
   that it does not fire right away but after x milliseconds?
2. Is there an option to see the input that fired the filter so that I
   can set focus back to that input?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Just found the answer myself. There is a `filterDelay` option that you can set on the table not ons the specific filter. The default settign is 300milliseconds

`<p-table [filterDelay]="900">`